# Directshow Live Source Filter Design

Tags: directshow, directshow.net

I am developing a Live DirectShow filter.

I have an H264 stream source which i can get streams via SDK API.

In my filter I have a Queue which i Enqueue (push) incoming stream from a thread.
Then I consume (Dequeue,pop) these streams inside the filter FillBuffer...

So I make a thread safe Queue...But this causes some problem....

At FillBuffer if i check is there any incoming packets and if there is , process 
logic is like this:

```
    ...
    bool hasElement = SynchronizedQueue.pop(element);

    if(!hasElement)
    {
        return S_OK
    }
    ...
```

**...this consume to much CPU...**

Howewer using boost lib to implement lock with condition variable

```
...
SynchronizedQueue.waitAndPop(element) ;// which wait until we have some
```

**Which have a lover CPU ...But sometime when there is no data in Queue, this block FillBuffer function and filter may not be stopped..**.

***So any design idea alternatives for a live source filter which takes input streams from a remote mechine and pass it to decoder?
    Or how can I make my design better....lower CPU and can be stopped?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source filter owns a pushing thread, so you need to wait there using a synchronization object (event, mutex) to yield control until a new frame is available for pushing off the output pin.

Whenever you receive a frame from SDK and you put it onto queue, you will indicate this availability using synchronization object, e.g. you will [set an event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The worker thread wlil see the event and start processing the frame.

The worker thread needs to be able to respond to two events, at least: a new frame, and filter/graph stop. So you will need [`WaitForMultipleObjects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to wait for multiple evetns and wake up on the first occurred.

Comment: Well, it's `IBaseFilter::Stop` called on your object, you can definitely handle it in addition to what you and base classes are already doing.